# Spring beans of dependency projects that are added to my main project are not being autowired

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have two projects:

1. ItemProject - contains spring-boot-starter dependencies. It has one domain object called Item, a service and a repository
2. ItemProjectConsumer - I have created this project just to test if i can add the ItemProject as dependency and able to call the code ItemProject.

Here is the pom.xml for both

1. ItemProject

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ItemProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

2. ItemProjectConsumer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ItemConsumerProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>ItemProject</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Here are the Spring components from ItemProject

1.Domain

```
package org.example.ItemProject.beans;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String price;
    public Item(){}

    public Item(String name, String description, String price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", price='" + price + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

2.Service

```
package org.example.ItemProject.Service;

import org.example.ItemProject.beans.Item;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface ItemService {
    public Item addItem(Item item);
    public List<Item> getItems();
}
```

3.Repository

```
package org.example.ItemProject.Repository;

import org.example.ItemProject.Service.ItemService;
import org.example.ItemProject.beans.Item;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class ItemRepository implements ItemService {
    List<Item> items=new ArrayList<Item>();
    @Override
    public Item addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Here is the main class from ItemConsumerProject

```
package org.example.ItemConsumerProject;

import org.example.ItemProject.Service.ItemService;
import org.example.ItemProject.beans.Item;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Driver implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    ItemService service;
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Driver.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Driver.class,args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        for(String bean:context.getBeanDefinitionNames())
            logger.info(bean);
    }
}
```

I can see that the external dependencies list ItemConsumerProject
[image: External Dependencies Intellij]

But when i run my main class from ItemConsumerProject, am getting below exception
[image]

Comment: Try to add @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.example"}) to your Driver class

Comment: Thanks Man. It worked, but i don't understand one thing. If both my ItemProject and ItemConsumerProject has the basepackage as 'org.example', then i should be autowiring the components under org.example in my ItemConsumerProject with the help of @SpringBootApplication autoconfiguration right. Why didn't that happen. Any clue?